# Regenerate R.java without building entire project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

Is it possible to regenerate R.java without building an entire project, and without using Project -> Build Automatically?

Comment: Delete it and it'll be automatically regenerated.

Comment: Not for me. Are you using Project -> Build Automatically?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [in this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html), the thing responsible for making an `R.java` file is called 'aapt': The Android Asset Packaging Tool.

There are [several options](http://elinux.org/Android_aapt) for the tool, but basic usage help can be found by just typing in the name of the program (`aapt`) without any parameters, as shown on that page.

A note: if you didn't allready know this, and hadn't yet read all the files about manually building/compiling android apps, I'm not really sure this is where you want to be going. If it is to work around some sort of error, you're probably better of fixing the error :). If it's not, then it's of course  a valid method of building and compiling, just a little more work.